# CGroups memory limit not working

Tags: linux, debian, lxc, debian-jessie, cgroup

I am trying to limit memory usage for a LXC container using CGroups, but I can't limit the memory.

```
# lxc-cgroup -n maxdaniel981 memory.limit_in_bytes 134217728
lxc_container: failed to assign '134217728' value to 'memory.limit_in_bytes' for 'maxdaniel981'
```

Then I looked up `/proc/cgroups`:

```
# cat /proc/cgroups
#subsys_name    hierarchy       num_cgroups     enabled
cpuset  2       3       1
cpu     3       3       1
cpuacct 3       3       1
memory  0       1       0
devices 4       3       1
freezer 5       3       1
net_cls 6       3       1
blkio   7       3       1
perf_event      8       3       1
net_prio        6       3       1
```

It looks like `cgroups_memory` is disabled, but I enabled the kernel flag in `/etc/default/grub` and updated grub using `update-grub`

```
# cat /etc/default/grub
# If you change this file, run 'update-grub' afterwards to update
# /boot/grub/grub.cfg.
# For full documentation of the options in this file, see:
#   info -f grub -n 'Simple configuration'

GRUB_DEFAULT=0
GRUB_TIMEOUT=5
GRUB_DISTRIBUTOR=`lsb_release -i -s 2> /dev/null || echo Debian`
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="cggroup_enable=memory swapaccount=1"
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="cggroup_enable=memory swapaccount=1"
```

CGroup is mounted in `/etc/fstab` like this;

```
cgroup        /sys/fs/cgroup  cgroup  defaults        0       0
```

Can somebody help me with this issue? I am using Debian Jessie, and my kernel version is 3.16.0-4-amd64.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's a small typo in your [GRUB configuration](https://wiki.debian.org/LXC); `cgroup` not `cggroup` should do the trick:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="cgroup_enable=memory swapaccount=1"
```

Comment: Thank you, I don't know how I could have missed that.... (I have to wait 15 hours to reward the bounty).

Comment: Good catch!  +1 from me for this answer - but also +1 for the question, for **showing** us the relevant code, instead of just **telling** us "*I enabled the kernel flag in grub*", or somesuch.  I wish more questions were so concisely but informatively written.

Comment: @MadHatter Thanks! I completely agree with you. I rarely ask questions, much of what I need to know is already on these forums. And, this also may help others with the same question or problem.